# MSAL AcquireTokenWithDeviceCode ExecuteAsync hangs

Tags: c#, azure, graph, azure-ad-msal

My calls to AcquireTokenWithDeviceCode and using ExecuteAsync() on the returned object never return.

A breakpoint in the deviceCodeResultCallback is hit as expected and I do get the instructions in the deviceCodeResult object Message property to open https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter code XXXXXXXX to authenticate. After pressing Continue in the debugger and then using fiddler, I can see the periodic requests being made waiting for me to approve the requested scopes access, where it gets an expected error of authorization_pending while waiting for approval. After successfully authorizing the scopes for the account in a browser using the aforementioned URL, Fiddler gets the JSON containing access_token, client_token, et al in its last recorded HTTP call. However, the ExecuteAsync() call never returns. It appears the expected result should be a Task object. Below is the code I am running for my experimentation. There are breakpoints set on the "return result;" and "return null;" lines, as well as all CLR exceptions are being captured.

Of note after successfully authenticating above, if I pause the program and drill down into the pca.UserTokenCache I do see the account show up in a collection with all expected info, i.e. ClientName, Token, etc.

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 16.7.0, with the Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.18.0 NuGet package. The project TargetFramework is .NET Framework 4.7.2, and is a simple Windows Application with a single "Run" button that uses a PublicClientApplicationBuilder to create the pca object referenced in the source below. Additionally, the application is set up in Azure to treat the application as a public client, and the (only) Redirect URI is set to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient.

```cs
try
{
    var result = await pca.AcquireTokenWithDeviceCode(scopes,
        deviceCodeResult =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(deviceCodeResult.Message);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }).ExecuteAsync();

    Debug.WriteLine(result.Account.Username);

    return result;
}
catch (MsalServiceException)
{
    return null;
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    return null;
}
catch (MsalClientException)
{
    return null;
}
catch
{
    return null;
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing some concept but am running out of obvious ideas. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original thread may be busy making the synchronization context unavailable. Try the following:

```cs
var result = await pca.AcquireTokenWithDeviceCode(scopes,
    deviceCodeResult =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(deviceCodeResult.Message);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }).ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks Alfredo. The ConfigureAwait() call is most likely needed because the call is being made within a WinForms button-click method. For more details as to the "why", the Microsoft .NET Blog has a post called "ConfigureAwait FAQ". The link at this time is: [https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/)

Comment: @jmullis You're welcome! Thanks for the extra information.